# Size the DIV to the size of the background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a DIV with the following style

```
.vplayer-container .logo
{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 50px;
 right: 10px;
 background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 max-width: 50px;
 max-height: 50px;
}
```

I want that the DIV size is the same as the background image. Since the bg image change, I want it to be set automatically. I can use JavaScript, but I'd prefer a CSS way for that.

I'm targeting **HTML5 browsers** that is FireFox, Webkit and Opera.

Thanks

**Answer:**

With *Kyle Sevenoaks* hint, you can do it by putting an image element inside the DIV.

```
<div>
<img src="url">
</div>
```

Remove the Background property and no other styling is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS can't do this, the div gets its dimensions from the content within it. The background image is purely a mark of styling.

You should be able to do this with Javascript, finding the height and width values and injecting them into an inline style should do it :)

You can also use an `<img>` tag within the `.logo` div. This would produce what you intend.

Comment: Thanks, That is the answer I was looking for :) Put an image within the DIV and everything should go fine.

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot do that for background image.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm targeting HTML5 browsers only

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible with pure CSS. I think you need to do it with JavaScript. Do you really need this to be dynamic? I think it is less work to change two values in the stylesheet if the logo changes.

Comment: This is a script, the user can put the values; however, doing it for him will make things a lot easier.