# Set the height of a div to match its background-image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KypNdy)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 paddinglist">
            <div class="inner-img">
                <img class="bg-img" src="http://merchandiser-szcel9eb49h.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/home-v3-g1.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="category_name">
                <a href="#">Art & Frames</a>
                <p class="category_desc">Celiac cornhole vice neutra. Succulents freegan four dollar toast pop-up, meggings brooklyn flexitarian irony snackwave. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 paddinglist">
            <div class="inner-img">
                <img class="bg-img" src="http://merchandiser-szcel9eb49h.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/home-v3-g2.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>  
            <div class="category_name">
                <a href="#">Art & Frames</a>
                <p class="category_desc">Brooklyn vexillologist vice chia keytar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
  jQuery(".bg-img").each(function() {
        var urlImg = jQuery(this).attr('src'),
        parent = jQuery(this).parent();
        $(this).remove();
        parent.css(
        {
        'background':'url("'+urlImg+'") no-repeat 50% 0',
        'background-size': 'cover'
        });
    });
```

I put a background on a div but the picture is not visible because the height is 0.

How can I make a dynamic height for div?

Comment: `dynamic height` According to what?

Comment: I want a height that allows to see the whole picture

Comment: But the height of these photos is not the same, no problem with this?

Comment: See this link : https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/NwqbeM

I think this is what that you want. I also give same answer bellow.

Comment: Possile duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778815/size-the-div-to-the-size-of-the-background-image

Answer (score 0):

You can add height in your js code itself as shown below

```
 jQuery(".bg-img").each(function() {
        var urlImg = jQuery(this).attr('src'),
        parent = jQuery(this).parent();
        $(this).remove();
        parent.css(
        {
        'background':'url("'+urlImg+'") no-repeat 50% 0',
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'height': this.height,
        'width': this.width
        });
    });
```

Comment: but in this method the height of 100px does not fit for both images.
I need something dynamic

Comment: on what basis do you want to set that height?

Comment: I want a height that allows to see the whole picture

Answer (score 0):

You can set dynamic height for the images using `height:this.height` like this.
`this.height` will return height of the image and that will solve your issue

```
jQuery(".bg-img").each(function() {
    var urlImg = jQuery(this).attr('src'),
    parent = jQuery(this).parent();
   $(this).remove();
    parent.css(
    {
    'background':'url("'+urlImg+'") no-repeat 50% 0',
     height:this.height,
    'background-size': 'cover'

    });
});
```

CodePen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqJOvm

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
jQuery(".bg-img").each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this),
            urlImg = $this.attr('src'),
            parent = $this.parent(),
            imgHeight = $this.height();

        parent.height(imgHeight);
        parent.css(
        {
            'background':'url("'+urlImg+'") no-repeat 50% 0',
            'background-size': 'cover'
        });

        $this.remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This your solution:

```
  jQuery(".bg-img").each(function() {
        var urlImg = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            var imgHeight = $(this).height();
        parent = jQuery(this).parent();
       $(this).remove();
        parent.css(
        {
        'background':'url("'+urlImg+'") no-repeat 50% 0',
        'background-size': 'cover',
          'height': imgHeight
        });
    });
```

**Here is preview link:** https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/NwqbeM